# Custom Tag Lib in Grails is Not Working

Tags: grails

I am new in grails and try to learn grails. I did a lot of googling but  unable to find the cause please help.The necessary codes are below:
Controller:

```
class TagLibTestController {
def dateTest() {
    def Date date=new Date()
    date.setTime(1379874600000)
    render date
 }
}
```

TagLib:

```
 class DateTagLib {
def dateFromNow = { attrs,body ->
    def date = attrs.date1
    println "DateTagLib"
    def niceDate = getNiceDate(date)
    out << niceDate
}

 String getNiceDate(Date date) {
    def now = new Date()
    def diff = Math.abs(now.time - date.time)
    final long second = 1000
    final long minute = second * 60
    final long hour = minute * 60
    final long day = hour * 24
    def niceTime = ""
    long calc = 0;
    calc = Math.floor(diff / day)
    if (calc) {
    niceTime += calc + " day" + (calc > 1 ? "s " : " ")
    diff %= day
    }
    calc = Math.floor(diff / hour)
    if (calc) {
    niceTime += calc + " hour" + (calc > 1 ? "s " : " ")
    diff %= hour
    }
    calc = Math.floor(diff / minute)
    if (calc) {
    niceTime += calc + " minute" + (calc > 1 ? "s " : " ")
    diff %= minute
    }
    if (!niceTime) {
    niceTime = "Right now"
    } else {
    niceTime += (date.time > now.time) ? "from now" : "ago"
    }
    return niceTime
    }
}
```

GSP Page:

```
 <g:dateFromNow date1="${date}"/>
```

We get only Date value. Tag Lib Class is not even execute any line. Any More configuration is required?

Comment: Your controller dateTest method is not rendering a view or template. How are you getting to the gsp page?

Comment: oh? it's my mistake but thanks a lot

Comment: You should create your own name space for your tag lib.

Comment: @Abdullah ok i got it and i will remember it when we make a real time application